# Trigger click event on existing map marker

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, angular, esri-loader

I am showing some markers using latitude and longitude, but there is a navigation drawer view, where I can click on the location.

So if I click on any particular location from the drawer, how can I trigger the click event on the associated marker?

Is there any way I can trigger the location item click from drawer to trigger marker click?

```
 let marker = new Graphic({
  geometry: {
    longitude: item.longitude,
    latitude: item.latitude,
    type: 'point',
    spatialReference: { wkid: 3857 },
  },
  symbol: this._Constants.MARKER_FLAT,

  popupTemplate: {
    title: item.name,
    content: function () {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = `<p>Testing</p>`;
      return div;
    },
  },
});

marker.setAttribute('id', String(item.id));
marker.setAttribute('name', String(item.name));

this.mapView.graphics.add(marker);
this.marker = marker;
```

This Is how I plot the markers

I have tried this approach, but the emit event is returning false.

```
 if (
  // this.mapView.emit('click', {  // tried this as well
  this.mapView.map.emit('click', {
    mapPoint: this.marker,
  })
 ) {
  console.log('Triggered');
 } else {
  console.log('NOT Triggered');
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the purpose of your "trigger a click event" is specifically to make the popup display for your "this.marker", then you can use [view.popup.open](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html#open) to trigger/open the popup.

The `view.popup.open` can take several inputs, including a location to look for features or to display a popup without a specific feature. There are several code snippets at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html#open

Based on your code:

```
    view.popup.open({
      location: this.marker.geometry, // location of the click on the view
      fetchFeatures: true // display the content for the selected feature if a popupTemplate is defined.
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, @Bjorn, I think I was looking at this requirement from a different perspective, click and click events, I should have spent more time on the documentation. Thanks for your help, I definitely helped. Totally appreciate it.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but anyways marking answer as accepted and giving you the bounty points